# Why is a class' size affected when it contains only a virtual function?

Tags: c++, function, virtual

```
class classWithNoVirtualFunction
{
    public:
        int   a;
        void x () 
        {
            char c;
            c = 'a';
        }
};

class classWithOneVirtualFunction
{
public:
   int          a;
   virtual void x () {}
};

class classWithTwoVirtualFunctions
{
public:
   int          a;
   virtual void x () {}
   virtual void y () {}
};

int main() 
{
   cout << "\nclassWithNoVirtualFunction's size: "   << sizeof (classWithNoVirtualFunction);    
   cout << "\nclassWithOneVirtualFunction's size: "  << sizeof (classWithOneVirtualFunction);
   cout << "\nclassWithTwoVirtualFunctions's size: " << sizeof (classWithTwoVirtualFunctions);

   cout << "\nvoid*'s size : " << sizeof (void*);
}
```

W.R.T the above code, Thinking in C++ says:

> This example required at least one data member. If there had been no
>   data members, the C++ compiler would have forced the objects to be a
>   nonzero size because each object must have a distinct address. If you
>   imagine indexing into an array of zero-sized objects, you’ll
>   understand. A “dummy” member is inserted into objects that would
>   otherwise be zero-sized.

**My question:** Now, I am not able to understand *what && how EXACTLY* happens if we have a class with zero members and a virtual function. Please explain with some programming examples.

Comment: I don't really see how this can be explained with *programming examples* beyond what you already added (removing the `int`). BTW, the expected output of the program would be ( 1, x, x, x ), where x is the size of a pointer in your architecture (commonly 4/8 for 32/64 bit architectures).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Strictly speaking, there's no requirement that the first output be 1, only that it not be 0.  On a word addressed machine (Unisys mainframe), I would expect it to be the size of a word, and all of the values to be identical.  Strictly speaking, there's also no requirement that the remaining values be identical either; I've worked on hardware where a `void*` was larger than what would be needed for the `vptr`.  (But that was before the days of C++; I don't think any such beasts are still around.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever a class contains at least one virtual function, the compiler needs to add RunTime Type Information to each of the objects. The implementation will usually add a single pointer to each object that refers to a structure, defined by the compiler and hidden from users, with a pointer to the `type_info` object and the `vtable` used for dynamic dispatch of functions.

In the case of a class with no non-static data members and at least one virtual function, the size of each object is the size of the per-object RTTI information (one pointer), and because that is non-zero, the compiler will not add extra space. What the quote is saying is that `sizeof(T) != 0` for any and all types `T`, and a type with a dynamic function trivially fits that requirement. Only with types that would have zero size, the compiler is forced to make the object 1 char big.

Comment: and what's `RunTime Type Information`? I didn't understand this `the size of each object is the size of the per-object RTTI information (one pointer), and because that is non-zero, the compiler will not add extra space. ` I didn't understand your answer well.

Comment: RTTI is RunTime Type Information includes both type information and the virtual table for function dispatch. For objects with no virtual functions, the `typeid` of the object (accessed through pointer or reference) is the static type of the pointer or reference: `nonvirtual *p = f(); typeid(*p);` will be resolved at compile time to be `typeid(nonvirtual)`, but if the type `virt` has virtual functions, then `virt *p = f(); typeid(*p);` will provide you with the type information of the most derived object, that might be `virt` or an object derived from it.

Comment: The second side of RTTI is the virtual table, which is the common implementation of the dispatch mechanism, basically a table containing function pointers to all of the virtual functions in the object. The `base` subobject in the hierarchy will contain one pointer to one such table (`vptr`), and each `derived` type in the hierarchy will overwrite the `vptr` to refer to different `vtable`s that hold pointers to the *final-overrider* of the virtual functions at each level. For efficiency, the `type_info` and `vtable` are bound together in a structure, and each object holds a single pointer.

Comment: David and @sellibitze In that quote of OP, what has size 0 to do with distinct addressing?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: I don't have access to the book, but the quote refers to basically this: `struct x {}; assert( sizeof(x)!=0 );`. Basically, even if an object is *empty*, the size must be guaranteed not to be 0, so that `x array[10]; assert(&x[0]!=&x[1]);` --i.e. each object is located in a different memory address (or a pointer to an object can be used to uniquely identify that object)-- Did you add the `int a` field to the types? If it was in the book, and the quote refers to that piece of code, then the book has an error.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard does not define the complete layout of a class. This is up to the compiler vendor. But the C++ standard does make some guarantees. For example, the size of a complete object is always greater than zero. The reason for this rule is hinted at by the text you quoted from Thinking in C++. Virtual functions of a simple class are *usually* implemented in terms of an additional hidden pointer member that identifies the object's dynamic type so that it's possible to invoke the correct function of the object's dynamic type. Since this additional hidden member adds to the size of the class, the compiler doesn't need to put any padding in there to make the class have a non-zero size.

But these are mostly implementation details you should not worry about too much. As long as you only rely on the guarantees the C++ standard makes, you should be fine.